# Como criar um acumulador

Tags: python

Tenho algumas turmas quero que exiba quantidade de alunos aprovados.

O que já fiz

```
nota= a 

if nota >= 60 and nota < 100:     
   

else:
```

Saída aprovados 20 reprovados 50, mas tenho setenta alunos. Como fazer?

Answer (score 2):

Se você possui uma lista com as notas dos alunos nas turmas, basta você verificar quantos valores são maiores que 60. Você pode fazer isso com a função `len()` e filtrar as notas utilizando compreensão de listas:

```
notas = [60, 75, 55, 86, 97, 90, 59]
qtd_aprovados = len([nota for nota in notas if nota >= 60])

print(f'Foram aprovados {qtd_aprovados} alunos')
```

Para este exemplo, aparecerá que foram aprovados 5 alunos.

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas formas diferentes de se fazer isso, mas como acredito que esteja começando, a ideia seria visualizar cada etapa de estrutura utilizada para entender.

Uma forma inicial seria ter uma lista, ou alguma outra estrutura de dados para ter todas as notas. Utilizando lista seria algo assim

```
notas = [95, 60, 50, 30, 20, 10]
```

Em seguida criar duas variáveis para armazenar os totais para aprovados e reprovados, que pode ser feito da seguinte maneira

```
total_aprovados = 0, total_reprovados = 0
```

Utilizar uma estrutura iterativa para que possa recuperar e identificar cada elemento da sua lista e para cada nota verificar conforme a condição necessária

```
for nota in notas:
    if nota >= 60 and nota < 100:
    else:
```

Dependendo do resultado dessas condicionais incrementar os valores das variáveis

```
total_aprovados = total_aprovados + 1 ou total_reprovados = total_reprovados + 1
```

Juntando tudo ficaria assim

```
notas = [95, 60, 50, 30, 20, 10]
total_aprovados = 0
total_reprovados = 0

for nota in notas:
    if nota >= 60 and nota < 100:
        total_aprovados = total_aprovados + 1
    else:
        total_reprovados = total_reprovados + 1

print('Total aprovados = {0}, Total reprovados = {1}'.format(total_aprovados, total_reprovados))
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe a possibilidade de se os alunos serem inseridos em um dicionario, e facilita a consulta de quem são os alunos reprovados.

Segue esse exemplo abaixo, aqui eu limitei os alunos ate 5 e inseri eles manualmente mas você pode alterar para a sua necessidade sem problemas.

```
alunos = {}
aprovados = []
reprovados = []

i = 0
qtd = 5

while i < qtd:
    aluno = str(input('Digite o nome do Aluno: '))
    nota = float(input('Digite a nota do Aluno: '))

    alunos[aluno]=nota
    i += 1

    if nota >= 60 and nota < 100:
        aprovados.append(aluno)

    else:
        reprovados.append(aluno)

print(alunos)
print(f'Os alunos aprovados foram {aprovados} e são um total de {len(aprovados)}')
print(f'Os alunos aprovados foram {reprovados} e são um total de {len(reprovados)}')
```

Comment: Dica: a condição `nota >= 60 and nota < 100` pode ser melhor escrita como `60 <= nota <= 100` (igual a 100 também, pois é uma nota válida)

Comment: sim fica mais legível da forma como você citou, eu ainda colocaria as médias de aprovado como variáveis para facilitar uma eventual troca parâmetros de aprovação